# Optimizing URL Parameters for Google Search

Tags: url, canonical-url, google-ranking, url-parameters

My website isn't ranking great on Google, so I've been going through pages to see what I can optimize. I've come across one section of the website where there are 5 pages, but the url is dynamically created based on user search, and has about 5000 potential options per page.

As an example, the way I currently have it, one of the URLs becomes [www.stockdeepdive.com/financials/AAPL/peratio](http://www.stockdeepdive.com/financials/AAPL/peratio)
where AAPL is the parameter (and there are about 5000 additional options for AAPL, representing stock tickers.. example [www.stockdeepdive.com/financials/GOOG/peratio](http://www.stockdeepdive.com/financials/GOOG/peratio) ).

When creating the website I thought this would be better, as it would provide more URLs to potentially rank on Google, and people are likely searching for a specific parameter(such as "AAPL pe ratio") rather than just a generic "pe ratio" search. The problem is they don't seem to be ranking very good/at all.

Does anyone know if this is the proper way to use these URLs? Or would something like [www.stockdeepdive.com/financials/peratio?AAPL](http://www.stockdeepdive.com/financials/peratio?AAPL) be better? Or does it matter? Can I just go in Search Console and request indexing for the 500 most popular stock ticker URLs?

Thanks!

Comment: Does each url have unique content ?

Comment: Yes, each url has unique content

Comment: Including meta description, title and canonical ???

Comment: Yes, meta description, title different. I believe the canonical also different but still trying to get a full grasp on what that is exactly

Comment: When you have duplicate pages, you nominate one of them as the one you want indexed by putting its URL in this tag.  If more than one page has the same canonical, only one of them will get indexed.  What does GS Console say when you do a liv URL test for one that's not indexed ?

Comment: It says URL is unknown to Google, but is available to be indexed/crawled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urls get discovered by Google

- If they are linked externally
- If they are linked internally
- If they are in a sitemap that you submit.

Even then, Google is under no obligation to index all your URLs.

**The easiest solution is to generate multiple sitemaps and submit them.**